# How to start stopped container using kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Business requirement is following:

1. Stop running container
2. Modify environment (Ex.Change value of DEBUG_LEVEL environment variable)
3. Start container

This is easily achievable using docker CLI

`docker create/docker stop/docker start`

How to do it using kubernetes?

Additional info:
We are migrating from Cloud Foundry to Kubernetes. In CF, you **deploy application**, **stop application**, **set environment variable**, **start application**. The same functionality is needed.
For those who are not aware of CF application. It is like docker container with single running (micro)service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you would run your application as a Deployment or as a StatefulSet. In this case, just change the value of the environment variable in the template and reapply the Deployment (or StatefulSet). Kubernetes will do the rest for you.

click here to refer the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment)

Comment: StatefulSet is looking promising. Containers maintain state across restarts and that state could change.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are creating a pod/deployment/statefulset using the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f blueprint.yaml
```

blueprint.yaml is the YAML file which contains the blueprint of your pod/deployment/statefulset object.

#### Method 1 - If you specify the environment variables in the YAML file

Then you can change the blueprint.yaml to modify the value of environment variable, .
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Then execute same command again to apply the changes.

#### Method 2 - If you specify the environment variables in the dockerfile

You should build your docker image with a new tag. Then change the docker image tag in the blueprint.yaml file and execute the same command again to apply the changes.

#### Method 3

You can also delete and create the pod/deployment/statefulset again.

```
kubectl delete -f blueprint.yaml
```

```
kubectl apply -f blueprint.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another possibility :

1. Define container environment variables [using configmap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)
2. Let Kubernetes react upon ConfigMap changes. 
   It does not trigger restart of Pods by default, unless you change Pod spec somehow. 
   [Here](https://blog.questionable.services/article/kubernetes-deployments-configmap-change/) is an article, that describes how to achieve it using SHA-256 hash generated of our ConfigMap.